# How to get databases names from listDatabases in mongodb?

Tags: php, php-mongodb

I am getting objects from below query in mongodb in variable

```
     $dbases = $this->connection->listDatabases(); 

     var_dump($dbases);
```

like

```
        object(MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfoLegacyIterator)#10 (1) { ["databases":"MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfoLegacyIterator":private]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(3) "MGL" ["sizeOnDisk"]=> float(3596288) ["empty"]=> bool(false) } [1]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(10) "SiteStatus" ["sizeOnDisk"]=> float(32768) ["empty"]=> bool(false) } [2]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(5) "admin" ["sizeOnDisk"]=> float(32768) ["empty"]=> bool(false) } [3]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(6) "config" ["sizeOnDisk"]=> float(12288) ["empty"]=> bool(false) } [4]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(5) "local" ["sizeOnDisk"]=> float(73728) ["empty"]=> bool(false) } } }
```

I want to extract database names only like MGL,SiteStatus from this object.
Please help me in extracting them through php code. I have tried like

```
            foreach ($dbases['databases'] as $dbs) 
            {    
                $dbname = $dbs['name'];                              
            }
```

It is not working. Please help!!!

Comment: Try `foreach ($dbases->databases as $dbs) `

Comment: Cannot access private property MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfoLegacyIterator::$databases i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to iterate over the Iterator, like this:

```
foreach($this->connection->listDatabases() as $database)
{
    echo $database->getName();
}
```

Each `$database` is an object of class [MongoDB\Model\DatabaseInfo](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/class/MongoDBDatabase/) which has a method [getName()](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBModelDatabaseInfo-getName/).